# Function Javascript copy

Tags: javascript, html, copy-paste

I have a problem,
I want to import the text of a text area from an HTML file to a javascript function contained in another HTML file to copy that in the clipboard through a button.
Do you know how this can be done?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. please have a read of the [help] and the [ask] section in particular - I would also recommend you take the [tour]

Comment: You're trying to get the value of an element in a file from a different file?

Comment: yes. Only the textArea

Comment: I think it isn't possible to just move it in to another file, without a backend system. HTML & JS themselves cannot change file content.

Comment: ok, I'm a beginner, so i don't know a lot of this language. thanks for the answer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.